# Clone Wordpress site from development server to live server

Tags: migration, staging, clone-site

I created a site in WordPress on my development server.

Now, I want it to go live.

I copied over all the files from the development server to the live server.

Created a new database for WP with new user and changed the credentials in `wp-config.php` file.

I have also changed the `siteurl` URL and `home` URL in the database table `wp_options`, however, still can't access the site giving me "**Page Load Timeout**". What am I missing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure you follow the Codex advises when [Moving your WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), from what you said, it's not clear to me if you export/import the database or just did the changes you mentioned.

Comment: All that changed is the domains name, from "dev.mysite.com" to "mysite.com". I have exported and imported the database changing the siteurl and home url like mentioned above.

Comment: Check the link, and follow those step when Moving your WordPress. The database is not imported just doing that, that is not the way to do it in fact,

Comment: I see... I will give it a go now and let you know if it worked. Thanks for the link

Comment: done... I thought changing the `siteurl` and `home` values to the new site url would do the trick but it came out it's being used somewhere else in the db. All done now tho. Thanks.